# Why does the PrimeVue tooltip have a graphical error?

Tags: css, vue.js, primevue

After upgrading to primevue@3.38.1, all tooltips have a graphical error in front of them: [image]

The code associated with this button is:

`<Button class="p-panel-header-icon p-link mr-2" @click="toggle_account_dialog" v-tooltip.left="'Add Datasource Account'">`

What might be causing this?